# Cannot convert JTextField input to Integer

Tags: java, jtextfield

I am trying to create a program that can ask inputs and automatically get the sum of the input from the JtextFields panel but I always get 0 value after the input. If you would like to see my whole line, hava a look below. Thanks in advance

```
{
JPanel myPanel = new JPanel();   
JTextField SGEAC1 = new JTextField("0",10);
String sgeac1tx = SGEAC1.getText();
int eac1sg = Integer.parseInt(sgeac1tx);

JTextField SGEAC2 = new JTextField("0",10);
String sgeac2tx = SGEAC2.getText();
int eac2sg = Integer.parseInt(sgeac2tx);

    myPanel.add(new JLabel("SG-EAC1:"));
    myPanel.add(SGEAC1);
    myPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(15));

    myPanel.add(new JLabel("SG-EAC2:"));
    myPanel.add(SGEAC2);
    myPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(15));
    int IPLBW = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, myPanel, "BW", 
    JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
    int sumbw = eac1sg+eac2sg; }

 if (IPLBW == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
  JTextArea ta = new JTextArea(100, 100);
       ta.setText("INTERNATIONAL UPSTREAM LINK UPDATE"+"\n" + sumbw 
         + "\n"+"-----------------------------"
         + "\n"+"TOTALS SG BW:   "+ sumbw +"/"
         + "\n"+"-----------------------------"
         + "\n" + "SG via EAC1"+"            " + SGEAC1.getText()+"G"
         + "\n" + "SG via EAC2"+"            " + SGEAC2.getText()+"G");

 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JScrollPane(ta), "RESULT", 
 JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    ta.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    ta.setLineWrap(true);
    ta.setCaretPosition(0);
    ta.setEditable(false);
]
```

Comment: Does you give user the time to enter the numbers?

Comment: You're the one who's setting the values of your text fields to zero: `JTextField SGEAC1 = new JTextField("0",10);` At no point do you request user input before you do the math `int sumbw = eac1sg+eac2sg;`, so 0 is the expected result of 0 + 0.

Comment: The "0" is just added there as the default number inside the box when you compile, You will input the numbers on the JTextFields and remove the "0". I would like to calculate the sum of those number that I encoded to the Fields

Comment: Do you have aqny recommendation sir? i would appreciate it. Thanks